# Changing the cell height and cell width of multiple tables MS Word 365

Tags: microsoft-word, visual-basic

I have a MS Word Document which has over 100 tables. I want to change the cell width to be 0.54" and cell height to be 0.56" but I want to do them all at once but I don't know how to do it.

Please help
Thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: Either a Macro (i do not use macros much) or possibly (not sure) a Style which is a table and then select your tables to the Style.